# Unable to get profile data(like name, age, gender) from id_token on google SignIn/SignUp

Tags: reactjs, passport.js, google-signin

I am using below API

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
```

I am getting the id token from google but when I am using the same id token in below API
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=
I am not receiving the profile data. but when I am using the access token I am getting the profile data. issues seems to have only with id token

I have tried various values for scope like,

```
scope: ['profile', 'email'] 

scope: ["openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]

scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]

scope: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]
```

Expecting google profile data from id_token.